# Unknown type name error in C

Tags: c, struct, structure, declaration

I am trying out some basic datastructure stuff in C. And I am coming back to C after a long time. Here is my simple `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
    int data;
    LLNode *next; //Error: unknown type name 'LLNode'
}LLNode;
```

But it gives a compilation error as shown above. Is it because while compiling `struct` compiler is not aware of existence of `LLNode`? That means I must be first declaring `LLNode` before `struct`. Is it like that? If yes how I am supposed to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this that way:

```
typedef struct LLNode LLNode;

struct LLNode {
    int data;
    LLNode *next; //No error
};
```

You cannot use `LLNode` type before it is defined.
With this method you declare what is `LLNode` first. Even though `struct LLNode` is not defined yet, this declaration suffice to declare `LLNode *` members (but you could not declare a `LLNode` member yet) as a pointer's size does not depend on the pointer's type.

Comment: You might wanna add an explanation for why that works, for completeness sake.

Answer (score 6):

The data member `next` of the structure is declared the type `LLNode`, which is unknown.

The corrected example

```
typedef struct LLNode
{
    int data;
    struct LLNode *next; //Error: unknown type name 'LLNode'
}LLNode;
```

Take into account that the structure tag name and the typedef name are in different name spaces. So you may use these two names simultaneously like `struct LLNode` and just `LLNode`.

Answer (score 2):

The `typedef` is incomplete until the end, so `LLNode` is not available as a type name inside the `struct`. However, `struct` *tag* would be available, so you could do this:

```
typedef struct LLNode
{
    int data;
    struct LLNode *next;
} LLNode;
```

This produces a `struct` with an identical structure to what is in your post, because `struct LLNode` is `typedef`-ed to `LLNode`.

Comment: how this compares to defining `typedef` before `struct` as explained by @jdarthenay in answer below?

Comment: @Mahesha999 It's a matter of preference. Your `struct` definition is independent of `typedef`, you could combine them or separate them out as you wish; it does not matter to the compiler, as long as it sees both of them. Yet another possibility is to define `struct` without `typedef` first, and then add `typedef struct LLNode LLNode` at the end. The effect is going to be the same in all three cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
typedef struct LLNode LLNode;
struct LLNode
{
int data;  
LLNode *next;   
};
```

Comment: Hey you should use the embedded code inputter like what you see above in other answers, instead of displaying it like you have above. 
Click the "{}" button to put code in like that.